# Pictures getting Mixed when scrolling in UITable View Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, uiimage

I have a UITable View in my program with dequeueReusableCells
I should load several images from server and show them in slide show

I have a custom cell and in configuring each cell I download the images in DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async and in DispatchQueue.main.async I add the downloaded pic to the slide show images

but when I start scrolling some of the cells that shouldn't have any pictures , have the repeated pics of another cell

Do you have any idea what has caused this ?!

I'm using swift and also ImageSlideShow pod for the slide show in each cell

Here is some parts of my code :

In my news cell class I have below part for getting images:

```
class NewsCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var Images: ImageSlideshow!
    @IBOutlet weak var SubjectLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var NewsBodyLbl: UILabel!

    func configureCell(news: OneNews) {


        self.SubjectLbl.text = news.Subject
        self.NewsBodyLbl.text =  news.Content



        if news.ImagesId.count==0{
            self.Images.setImageInputs([ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceholderIcon")!)])
        } 
        else{
            for imgId in news.ImagesId {

                let Url = URL(string: "\(BASE_URL)\(NEWS_PATH)/\(imgId)/pictures")
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

                    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: Url!)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        if let d = data {
                            let img = UIImage(data: data!)!
                            imageSrc.append(ImageSource(image: img))
                            self.Images.setImageInputs(imageSrc);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    self.Images.slideshowInterval = 3

}
```

And this is cellForRow method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = generalNewsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewsCell" , for: indexPath) as!  NewsCell

    if let news = NewsInfo.sharedInstance.getGeneralNews(){
        cell.configureCell(news: news[indexPath.row])

    }
    return cell

}
```

getGeneralNews() is a getter that returns an array of news 
so what I'm doing in cellForRowAt is that I get the news in the given index path and configure my cell with it .

```
class NewsInfo {

static var sharedInstance = NewsInfo()

private init(){}

private (set) var generalNews:[OneNews]!{
    didSet{
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name:
            NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "GeneralNewsIsSet"), object: nil)
    }
}
func setGeneralNews(allGeneralNews:[OneNews]){
    self.generalNews = allGeneralNews
}
func getGeneralNews() -> [OneNews]!{
    return self.generalNews
}
}
```

Each news contains an array of the picture Ids

These are the fields in my OneNews class
        var Subject :String!
        var Content:String!
        var ImagesId:[Int]!

Thanks !

Comment: Why don't you show your `getGeneralNews()` and `configureCell(news:)`? You may be doing something wrong with these methods. For example, if `getGeneralNews()` is an asynchronous method, something you described can easily happen. Anyway show enough code to resolve your issue.

Comment: @OOPer I just edited the question . Please let me know if any other part of the code could help  and thanks for your time and effore ! :)

Comment: OOPer asked you to post the code for those 2 methods. Maybe you should edit your question to show those methods?

Comment: THe problem is that you are assuming that your calls to `Data(contentsOf: Url!)` will complete in the order in which you issue them. They likely will not. You should create a dictionary keyed by URL and use that to find your images. Actually, you probably don't want to load all of your images into an array in memory. If your table view gets large you will run out of memory and crash. Better to save your files to disk and keep an array of optional file URLS.

Comment: @DuncanC So doesn't loading them as URLs over and over takes time and make the app stop working for seconds?!You mean like every time I wanna load a pic I should get it from its URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. The main idea of this code is giving a unique number to check if the cell is reused.

- I have renamed many properties in your code, as Capitalized identifiers for non-types make the code hard to read. You cannot just replace whole definition of your original `NewsCell`.
- There was no declaration for `imageSrc` in the original definition. I assumed it was a local variable. If it was a global variable, it might lead other problems and you should avoid.

(Important lines marked with `###`.)

```
class NewsCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var images: ImageSlideshow!
    @IBOutlet weak var subjectLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var newsBodyLbl: UILabel!

    //### An instance property, which holds a unique value for each cellForRowAt call
    var uniqueNum: UInt32 = 0

    func configureCell(news: OneNews) {
        self.subjectLbl.text = news.subject
        self.newsBodyLbl.text =  news.content


        let refNum = arc4random() //### The output from `arc4random()` is very probably unique.
        self.uniqueNum = refNum //### Assign a unique number to check if this cell is reused
        if news.imagesId.count==0 {
            self.images.setImageInputs([ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceholderIcon")!)])
        } else {
            var imageSrc: [ImageSource] = [] //###
            for imgId in news.imagesId {

                let Url = URL(string: "\(BASE_URL)\(NEWS_PATH)/\(imgId)/pictures")
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

                    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: Url!)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //### At this point `self` may be reused, so check its `uniqueNum` is the same as `refNum`
                        if self.uniqueNum == refNum, let d = data {
                            let img = UIImage(data: d)!
                            imageSrc.append(ImageSource(image: img))
                            self.images.setImageInputs(imageSrc)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        self.images.slideshowInterval = 3
    }
}
```

Please remember, the order of images may be different than the order of `imagesId` in your `OneNews` (as described in Duncan C's comment).

Please try.

Comment: I tested it and it worked ! Thanks so much for your time and help and also writing the code ! :-)))

Answer (score 2):

UITableViewCell are reused as you scroll. When a cell goes off the top of the screen, it will be reused for another row appearing at the bottom of the screen.

UITableViewCell has a method `prepareForReuse` you can override. You can use that method to clear out iamgeViews or any other state that should be reset or cancel downloading of images.

In your case, you probably shouldn't use `Data(contentsOf:)` since it doesn't give you a way to cancel it. `URLSessionDataTask` would be a better option since it lets you cancel the request before it finishes.

Comment: That was true . I couldn't use prepareForUse cause it seems it's no longer available but as you said the issue was that I needed to cancel downloading  cause the pics that had started to download , appeared in the new reused cell . Thanks for your help

Comment: `prepareForReuse` is still available. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a try with this small code fix, without overriding the prepareForReuse of the cell, just change in configure cell:

```
if news.ImagesId.count==0{
    self.Images.setImageInputs([ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceholderIcon")!)])
} 
else{
// STUFF
}
```

in

```
self.Images.setImageInputs([ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceholderIcon")!)]) 

if news.ImagesId.count > 0{
// STUFF
}
```

so every cell will start with the placeholderIcon even when reused

Comment: Thanks for your time though I tested it and it didn't work. I think the issue was , as said above , that when a cell was reusing pics for the previous cell were still downloading and even if we set a placeholder for the new cell the downloaded pics would replace that

Comment: Mmmh understand. So maybe with a dispatch task it can work too, canceling the previous one and creating a new one. Anyway you already get the solution so cheers :)